# How to change childhtml value twice in Magento

Tags: layout, blocks, parent-child-theme

I have a scenario such that the childhtml should be called in two different places of same parent template file and for each childhtml is called it should return a phtml which contains the variable getType should be changed.

**How is there**

------section1------

```
 $block->getChildBlock('demoPage')->setSection('section1');

  echo $block->getChildHtml('demoPage');
```

------section2------

```
  $block->getChildBlock('demoPage')->setSection('section2');

  echo $block->getChildHtml('demoPage');
```

In child phtml

```
echo $this->getSection();
```

The above one is the situation can anyone help this out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
//_____________SECTION 1 ____________

$s1Block = $block->getChildBlock('demoPage')->setSection('section1');
echo $s1Block->toHtml();


//_____________SECTION 2 ____________

$s2Block = $block->getChildBlock('demoPage')->setSection('section2');
echo $s2Block->toHtml();
```

or simply

```
$block->getChildBlock('demoPage')->setSection('something')->toHtml();
```

where `something` will vary in each call.